# Open RSA File and encrypt message with Python 3

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

I am dealing with this issue for some days and I don't get it. I have googled and tried several solutions indicated here, but without success. I want to encrypt a message (string) with a public key generated with `openssl`.

I am generating the keys with these commands:

```
# Private key:
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048

# Public key:
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public_key.pem
```

What I want to accomplish is to open the public key and encrypt the data with this snippet:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# Open RSA file
with open("public_key.pem", "r") as fk:
    rsa_key = RSA.importKey(fk.read())

message_encrypted = rsa_key.encrypt("Hello.", <X>)
```

I do not understand what do I have to write at `<X>`. But when I write some integer value, it fails with this error:

```
self = <Crypto.PublicKey._slowmath._RSAKey object at 0x7fcb153de748>, m = 'HELLO'

    def _encrypt(self, m):
        # compute m**d (mod n)
>       return pow(m, self.e, self.n)
E       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'str', 'int', 'int'
```

Best regards!

Comment: Are you using Pycrypto or Pycryptodome? Because in Pycrypto, K is ignored ([ref](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt)) and in Pycryptodome `.encrypt()` raises a `NotImplementedError` exception. So, with Pycrypto you should be able to use the method with any int as K, and with Pycryptodome you shouldn't be able to use the method at all.

Comment: From the traceback it seems `._encrypt()` is called at some point. The method expects `m` to be a number, but in this case it is a string, so in order to use it you should convert the message to a number. However this method performs raw encryption and it would be best to avoid it and use [OAEP](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html) instead.

Comment: @t.m.adam, I do not intend to use that parameter, that why I do not know what to write at <X>.

Comment: You can have any string or int as <X>, it is ignored eitherway. It is the `m` parameter (the message) that causes the exception.

Comment: Are you telling me it is a library's problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, because if you're using Pycrypto you should be able to use `.encrypt()` with a string for `m` any string or int for `K` and if you're using Pycryptodome you shouldn't be able to use `.encrypt()` at all, as I mentioned in a previous comment. Why don't you use `PKCS1_OAEP`? The link I shared documents it quite well.

Comment: As you can see in the snippet, I am only using this dependency `from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`

Comment: Sorry @t.m.adam, did not see your last comment. I was able to encrypt/decrypt with the link abour PKCS1_OAEP you provided. The thing now is, the result of the encription is a list of bytes, I have to convert those bytes to string in order to add that data to a json string, but I am getting unicode errores when decoding the string.

Comment: Yes, the result is a raw byte array which usually can't be UTF-8 encoded to a string. If you plan to store the ciphertext in JSON format, you'll have to Base64 encode it first.

Comment: Excellet @t.m.adam, you can post the answer if you desire and I will reply you as correct.

Comment: Thank you Nico but I won't post an answer. If you wish, you can post an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I was able to resolve this problem, not exactly with the class have I asked, but using another equivalent explained in this [site](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html).